# Design Pattern, any reference application (C++, Csharp, Java)

Tags: design-patterns

I am writing my final thesis and need to develop a Design Pattern Recognizer software. For testing I am looking for some open-source applications, which are applying design patterns systematically (and document them). I know JHotDraw and JUnit, but I would need applications written in C++ and C# as well. I have googled and found a (closed source) pattern framework for .NET and Jt, which is open but also written in java. I wonder if there's such a library for C++ and C#.

Comment: This should help: [Examples of GOF design patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good example of design patterns in C++ is [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/).  The most well-known probably being the [Signals and Slots pattern](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/signalsandslots.html), which is an extension/improvement of the Observer pattern. There's even a book about design patterns in Qt: [http://www.amazon.com/An-Introduction-Design-Patterns-Qt/dp/0131879057](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131879057)

Qt is not exactly open-source. But if you want open-source just to be able to view/examine the headers, then there shouldnt be any problems. Im pretty sure there shouldnt be any licensing issues if this is for your thesis, but you should probably contact them just in case.